# Will be Disposable resource disposed if try/catch is used inside "using" statement?

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, idisposable, sqlconnection

I'm working with `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

I have to catch an exception if, for example, there is any `SqlException`.

I'm using `using` clause and embed `try/catch block` inside of it. Here is the code:

```
public static void LogError(string error, string message)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStringWeb"]))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO errorLogTable (errorTime, errorType, error) VALUES(@errorTime, @errorText, @errorMsg)"))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.Prepare();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorTime", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorText", error);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorMsg", message);

        try
        {
           conn.Open();
           int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch { }
        }
   }
}
```

My question is, will my `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` be disposed in case of exception and is that a good approach to handle it or I should just simply use old fashion approach using `try/catch/finally` block?

Comment: This is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case the exception is catched right inside the using and the dispose is executed when you leave the using block.

But even if you put the using block outside the `try catch` and an exception is thrown, the dispose will be called.

```
public static void LogError(string error, string message)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connStringWeb"]))
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO errorLogTable (errorTime, errorType, error) VALUES(@errorTime, @errorText, @errorMsg)"))
            {
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorTime", DateTime.Now);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorText", error);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@errorMsg", message);

                conn.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
    }
    catch {}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `using` statement is just a syntactic shortcut for a `try`/`finally` block. So yes, the object inside the `using` will be disposed in the case of an exception being thrown. Put another way:

```
using(var foo = new Foo())
{
}
```

Essentially gets compiled into:

```
Foo foo;

try
{
    foo = new Foo();
}
finally
{
    foo.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can have the try catch within the using block or outside the using block. In both cases the SqlConnection and SqlCommand will be disposed.

However, I prefer to have the try catch outside the using to catch all errors, even object creation errors.

Comment: It is allowed (not "incorrect") to have two `using` statements like that, without a block `{ ... }` for the outermost `using`. Technically, `using` does not require a block; any embedded statement is OK.

Comment: This is different from the `try` statement where you must use a block after `try`.